# Error in int and tuple connection

Tags: python

I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple' 
Line 37
http://pastebin.com/LhMS9Xhx

filter = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
activefield = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
newvalue = 0
newvalue+= filter[iii][jjj]*aktuellesFeld[iii][jjj]
```

Comment: Please extract the minimum code to reproduce your problem and paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 37 is

```
            neuerGrauwert += filter[iii][jjj]*aktuellesFeld[iii][jjj]
```

`aktuellesFeld[iii][jjj] = im.getpixel((...))` is a tuple such as:

```
In [8]: im.getpixel((125,125))
Out[8]: (11, 11, 11, 255)
```

Multiplying by a float (like `filter[iii][jjj]`) concatenates copies of the tuple:

```
In [9]: 2*im.getpixel((125,125))
Out[9]: (11, 11, 11, 255, 11, 11, 11, 255)
```

But `neuerGrauwert` is an `int`. And you can not add a `tuple` to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

That's very straight forward: you can't add a tuple to an int. `aktuellesFeld[iii][jjj]` is a tuple, which you multiply with an int (`filter[iii][jjj]`) resulting in a tuple. You then add that tuple to another int (`neuerGrauwert`), and that's a `TypeError`

Your code is very unreadable. Why use variable names such as `iii` or `jjj`? Also, it's a bad idea to use `filter` as a variable name as it is a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

You try to add a tupel to an int. Look inside your tuple, extract the value you want, and *then* add it to the int.